# jQuery.Cycle showing small images at first load

Tags: jquery, image, cycle

I've got problem with jQuery.cycle plugin. At first load of page (when imgs aren't cached) it's showing small imgs, like thumbnails. You can see it at (edit: sorry, old link) - just wait when the second img shows - it's small. Reload/refresh solves it, but it's not real solution, you know.

Does anybody know what's the solution of this problem? Thanks a lot

Comment: Everything works fine on FF 3.6 RC2. On Chrome 4.0.249.64 (beta) too and even on IE6. What browser do you use?

Comment: I second what Balon says.  FF in OS X and IE7 in windows - looks great.

Comment: Hell, I'm using Opera/Win7, tested it in IE8 and FF3.5 too. My client has Safari/Mac I think and I have respone about bugged working of this from loads of ppl :-(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `$(window).load(function() {    });` rather than `$(document).ready(function() { });`

Answer (score 5):

Use `overflow:hidden` on the images container `DIV`

Comment: While this doesn't fix the OP issue, it does solve the flash of all images.

Answer (score 4):

Same issue.  Random images were getting inline styles of 24px x 24px.  Rather than setting each image height and width, I did so through CSS.  Since my width was a fixed width, I set that but set the height to 100%:

```
.ParentDiv img { width: 400px !important; height: 100% !important; }
```

The !important is necessary to override the inline styles applied by jQuery cycle.

This also seemed to solve another issue I was having with IE8.  The page would load fine, but the images seemed to be loading after all the CSS and jquery loaded.  This caused the box to not expand to fit the height and width of the images within.  I imagine setting the width and height, the box holding the images was sized right off the bat.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and it was driving me crazy! I tried pre-loading the images, checked versions on everything etc to no avail.. The only thing that seemed to fix this was setting width and height on each picture on the page, rather than in css.

Comment: Yup, this is what I did too after trying a million other things.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by setting the width and height in the `<img>` tag. But since I'm using a script to generate the list of images, and they sometimes have various sizes, I used a tiny bit of php to solve this:

```
function displayimage($filename) {
    $imgsize = getimagesize("$filename");
    echo "<img src=\"$filename\" $imgsize[3] />\n";
}
```

`$imgsize[3]` is, for example, `width="585" height="285"`.

And then, to show all jpgs in the directory in the slideshow:

```
<div class="slideshow">
<?php
foreach (glob("*.jpg") as $filename) {
    displayimage($filename);
}
?>
</div>
```

Output

```
<div class="slideshow">
<img src="cat.jpg" width="575" height="256" />
<img src="dog.jpg" width="475" height="350" />
<img src="frog.jpg" width="675" height="300" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> While possibly not directly answer to the question (the jQuery.cycle plugin is unknown to me), many of the answers here address the problem of processing images after loading and that's also what people come here to seek for. So here it goes what's going on:

The 24px come up due to faulty logic on browser side - returning prematurely dimensions for a placeholder control. They have a different control-logic for handling cached images, *IE* does not even trigger `onload` for them, and that's why all the confusion comes up.

More reliable than `(width===0)` checking to be found all over the internet if an image is loaded, the `.complete` DOM property seldom mentioned apparently supported by all major browsers: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_img_complete.asp

this worked for me:

```
$("img")
    .one('load', onLoadRoutine)
    .each(function() {
        if(!this.complete) {
            return; //.one() will fire eventually
        } else {
            onLoadRoutine({delegateTarget:this}); //fake event object
        }
    });
```

> Note the event mockup object `{delegateTarget:this}`. Preferable would be `jQuery(this).trigger('load')`, but I can't recommend it, since I didn't try it out at the time...

the `.complete` test should solve the case of the faulty 24px placeholder control's logic, the `.one('load').each()`. covers the control-flow split on cached/distant.